# Solve Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue problem with substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the SL-eigenvalue problem:

$x^4y''+\lambda y = 0$ with $y(1)=y(2)=0$.

Therefore one should:

1) substitute with y(x)=xv(x) to get a diferential equation for v(x) and then

2) substitute x=1/t.

I did 1) and get:

$x^5v''(x)+2x^4v'(x)+\lambda xv(x)=0$.

But then I get stuck at 2). If I substitute $x=1/t$ and respectively $v''(x)= v''(1/t)\cdot \frac{t^3}{2}$ and $v'(x)=v(1/t)\cdot (-t^2)$ I get:

$t^{-2}v''(1/t))-2t^{-2}v'(1/t) +\lambda t^{-1}v(1/t)=0$

Neither do I know how to solve this last equation nor do I know if it is correct. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do the substitution, it is better to take a new variable. Let $v(x)=f(t)$ where $t=1/x$.

It comes $v'(x)=t'f'(t)$ and $v''(x)=t''f'(t)+(t')^2 f''(t)$. So

$x^5(2/x^3) f'(t)+x^5(1/x^4)f''(t)+2 x^4t'f'(t)+(\lambda/t)f(t)=0$ giving

$(2/t^2) f'(t)+(1/t)f''(t)-(2/t^2)f'(t)+(\lambda/t)f(t)=0$ or else $f''(t)+\lambda f(t)=0$.